# How to convert datatype:object to float64 in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am going around in circles and tried so many different ways so I guess my core understanding is wrong. I would be grateful for help in understanding my encoding/decoding issues.

I import the dataframe from SQL and it seems that some datatypes:float64 are converted to Object. Thus, I cannot do any calculation. I fail to convert the Object back to float64.

**df.head()**

```
Date        WD  Manpower 2nd     CTR    2ndU    T1  　　T2    　　T3    　　T4 

2013/4/6    6   NaN     2,645   5.27%   0.29    407     533     454     368
2013/4/7    7   NaN     2,118   5.89%   0.31    257     659     583     369
2013/4/13   6   NaN     2,470   5.38%   0.29    354     531     473 　　383
2013/4/14   7   NaN     2,033   6.77%   0.37    396     748     681     458
2013/4/20   6   NaN     2,690   5.38%   0.29    361     528     541     381
```

**df.dtypes**

```
WD             float64
Manpower       float64
2nd             object
CTR             object
2ndU           float64
T1              object
T2              object
T3              object
T4              object
T5              object

dtype: object
```

SQL table:

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can convert most of the columns by just calling [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects):

```
In [36]:

df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.dtypes
Out[36]:
Date         object
WD            int64
Manpower    float64
2nd          object
CTR          object
2ndU        float64
T1            int64
T2          int64
T3           int64
T4        float64
dtype: object
```

For column '2nd' and 'CTR' we can call the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods to replace the thousands separator and remove the '%' sign and then [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) to convert:

```
In [39]:

df['2nd'] = df['2nd'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
df['CTR'] = df['CTR'].str.replace('%','').astype(np.float64)
df.dtypes
Out[39]:
Date         object
WD            int64
Manpower    float64
2nd           int32
CTR         float64
2ndU        float64
T1            int64
T2            int64
T3            int64
T4           object
dtype: object
In [40]:

df.head()
Out[40]:
        Date  WD  Manpower   2nd   CTR  2ndU   T1  　　T2   T3     T4
0   2013/4/6   6       NaN  2645  5.27  0.29  407   533  454    368
1   2013/4/7   7       NaN  2118  5.89  0.31  257   659  583    369
2  2013/4/13   6       NaN  2470  5.38  0.29  354   531  473  　　383
3  2013/4/14   7       NaN  2033  6.77  0.37  396   748  681    458
4  2013/4/20   6       NaN  2690  5.38  0.29  361   528  541    381
```

Or you can do the string handling operations above without the call to `astype` and then call `convert_objects` to convert everything in one go.

**UPDATE**

Since version `0.17.0` `convert_objects` is deprecated and there isn't a top-level function to do this so you need to do:

`df.apply(lambda col:pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce'))`

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and this related question: [pandas: to_numeric for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814100/pandas-to-numeric-for-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 40):

convert_objects is deprecated.

For pandas >= 0.17.0, use [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
df["2nd"] = pd.to_numeric(df["2nd"])
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem in a DataFrame (`df`) created from an Excel-sheet with several internal header rows.

After cleaning out the internal header rows from `df`, the columns' values were of "non-null object" type (`DataFrame.info()`).

This code converted all numerical values of multiple columns to int64 and float64 in one go:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[:,i] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,i], errors='ignore')
    # errors='ignore' lets strings remain as 'non-null objects'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X = np.array(X, dtype=float)
```

You can use this to convert to array of float in python 3.7.6

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df['2nd'] = pd.to_numeric(df['2nd'].str.replace(',', ''))
df['CTR'] = pd.to_numeric(df['CTR'].str.replace('%', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use regular expression to handle multiple items as the general case of this issue,

```
df['2nd'] = pd.to_numeric(df['2nd'].str.replace(r'[,.%]','')) 
df['CTR'] = pd.to_numeric(df['CTR'].str.replace(r'[^\d%]',''))
```