# Pandas how to replace multiple columns of str% to float number?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
          A        B         C       D        E      F
0    CEKAPE   23.60%   117.374   0.53%    0.11%    <2%
1    HYTFFZ   25.32%   116.250   1.88%    0.38%     5%
```

The df has several columns that contain percetage numbers as string type. This code only process one column at a time. `df['D'] = df['D'].str.strip('%').astype(float) / 100` How to write the code while dozens of cloumns need to be processed?

```
          A        B         C        D        E      F
0    CEKAPE   0.2360   117.374   0.0053   0.0011    <2%
1    HYTFFZ   0.2532   116.250   0.0188   0.0038   0.05
```

Comment: There's no way around it, you have to iterate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: to\_numeric for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814100/pandas-to-numeric-for-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors = coerce` and [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) 
avoiding having to use `apply`:

```
new_df = (pd.to_numeric(df.replace('%','',regex = True).stack(),
                        errors = 'coerce')
            .div(100)
            .unstack()
            .fillna(df))
print(new_df)
        A       B        C       D       E     F
0  CEKAPE   0.236  1.17374  0.0053  0.0011   <2%
1  HYTFFZ  0.2532   1.1625  0.0188  0.0038  0.05
```

or **`dropna = False`** and [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
new_df = (pd.to_numeric(df.stack(dropna = False).str.replace('%',''),
                        errors = 'coerce')
            .div(100)
            .unstack()
            .fillna(df)
         )
```