# Convert dictionary of dictionaries to dataframe with data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, column-types

What is the preferred way to convert dictionary of dictionaries into a data frame with data types?

I have the following kind of dictionary `r` which contains fact sets behind each key

```py
import pandas as pd

r = { 1:{'a':1,'b':2,'c':'b'},
      2:{'d':1,'b':1,'c':'b'},
      3:{'e':0} }
```

Converting this dictionary of dictionaries into a dataframe can be done in a quite straightforward way

```py
x = pd.DataFrame(r)
x
x.dtypes
```

which yields the following version on the original dictionary of dictionaries

```
     1    2    3
a    1  NaN  NaN
b    2    1  NaN
c    b    e  NaN
d  NaN    1  NaN
e  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

and the following datatypes for columns

```
1     object
2     object
3    float64
dtype: object
```

However, I would like to have transposed version on `x`. After doing so

```py
y = x.transpose()
y
y.dtypes
```

it seems like the expected representation on the data is shown in matrix form

```
     a    b    c    d    e
1    1    2    b  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    1    e    1  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    0
```

but the data types are all `object`

```
a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
e    object
dtype: object
```

What is the preferred way to do such conversion from `r` to `y` so that `y.dtypes` would yield directly data types

```
a    float64
b    float64
c    object
d    float64
e    float64
dtype: object
```

similar to converting `r` to `x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the right orientation (default is `columns`, you want `index`).

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r, orient='index')
```

---

```
a    float64
b    float64
c     object
d    float64
e    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

In `pandas` >= 1.0.0 you can use [`.convert_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html):

```
>>> y.convert_dtypes().dtypes

a     Int64
b     Int64
c    string
d     Int64
e     Int64
dtype: object
```

Note that this uses the new `pandas` string type, and will also use `pd.NA` for missing values.  There are parameters which affect some of the conversion:

```
>>> y.convert_dtypes(convert_string=False).dtypes

a     Int64
b     Int64
c    object
d     Int64
e     Int64
dtype: object
```

If you have older `pandas`, you could use `pd.to_numeric` with some sort of loop or `apply`, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43266945/13386979):

```
>>> y = y.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore') # for columns that fail, do nothing
>>> y.dtypes

a    float64
b    float64
c     object
d    float64
e    float64
dtype: object
```

I don't see a way to enforce numeric types on the whole dataframe without a loop ([`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) doesn't seem to work, as errors either cause the whole conversion to fail or if ignored, return the original data types).

---

I just saw that the documentation for `.transpose()` [addresses this point](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

> When the DataFrame has mixed dtypes, we get a transposed DataFrame with the object dtype:

*Transposing a mixed-type DatraFrame returns an object-type DataFrame.* Here's their example reproduced for completeness:

```
d2 = {'name': ['Alice', 'Bob'],
      'score': [9.5, 8],
      'employed': [False, True],
      'kids': [0, 0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2_transposed = df2.transpose()

print(df2, df2.dtypes, df2_transposed, df2_transposed.dtypes, sep='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
    name  score  employed  kids
0  Alice    9.5     False     0
1    Bob    8.0      True     0

#dtypes as expected
name         object
score       float64
employed       bool
kids          int64
dtype: object

              0     1
name      Alice   Bob
score       9.5     8
employed  False  True
kids          0     0

#dtypes are now object
0    object
1    object
dtype: object
```

So you **have to** include additional commands if you want the `dtypes` to be converted.

Comment: That `y.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')` seems to be closest answer so far. Although I was looking a direct way to go from `r` to `y` with number data types included.

Comment: Your solutions all address an XY problem. But the real problem is in the import process ;)

Comment: Haha your solutions were great, but they needed the premise that the data was already misimported first :p