# how to regularize numeric/non-numeric entries in pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numeric, coerce

I want to control for non-numeric entries in my pandas dataframe.
Say I have the following:

```
>>> df
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0   0.01    NaN    0.1
1    NaN    0.9    0.2
2   0.01    NaN    0.3
3   0.01    0.9    0.4
```

I can take the row-means as follows, while python properly skips over the NaN values:

```
>>> df.mean(axis=1)
0    0.055000
1    0.550000
2    0.155000
3    0.436667
dtype: float64
```

Great!. but now suppose one of the values from my imported table is a string

```
>>> df.iloc[0,1]="str1"
>>> df
   col_1 col_2  col_3
0   0.01  str1    0.1
1    NaN   0.9    0.2
2   0.01   NaN    0.3
3   0.01   0.9    0.4
>>> df.mean(axis=1)
0    0.055
1    0.200
2    0.155
3    0.205
dtype: float64
```

**DANGER:** the output looks plausible, but is wrong, because once I changed the value in position `[0,1]` to a string, the values in position `[1,1]` and `[3,1]` changed from being the number `0.9` to become the string `"0.9"`, and all the strings are omitted from averaging (I guess each column has to be of the same type? there's probably a reason, but boy this is dangerously subtle.)

What I want to do now is force all the entries of the dataframe back into numeric type. Anything that can be sensibly coerced into a number should become that number, and **anything** that cannot should become `nan` (regardless of what string or type it might have been).

Pandas *series* have a function `pandas.to_numeric` where you can set `errors='coerce'`, but unfortunately the analogous function for df's (`DataFrame.astype()`) doesn't allow this option.

Is there a function for "make every element of the dataFrame that looks like a number numeric, and make everything else `nan`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `to_numeric` on a subset of columns with `apply`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814100/pandas-to-numeric-for-multiple-columns) might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can `apply`, which by default will perform on the columns:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mean(1)
```