# Casting types of all columns starting with Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a df and several columns starting with `'comps'` and I want to cast their types to float.

I tried

```
df = df.convert_dtypes() - Not Ok

df = df.columns.startswith('comps').astype(float) - Failed
```

Is there a fast way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all columns starting by `comps` and casting to floats:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('comps')], 'float')

d = dict.fromkeys(df.filter(regex='^comps').columns, 'float')
df = df.astype(d)
print (df)
```

Or:

```
m = df.columns.str.startswith('comps')
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].astype(float)
print (df)
```

Or:

```
c = df.filter(regex='^comps').columns
df[c] = df[c].astype(float)
print (df)
```

Or:

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='^comps').astype(float))
print (df)
```

---

If casting to floats failed, is necessary use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
m = df.columns.str.startswith('comps')
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print (df)
```

Or:

```
c = df.filter(regex='^comps').columns
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print (df)
```

Or:

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='^comps').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
print (df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814100/pandas-to-numeric-for-multiple-columns ?

Comment: @Corralien - ya, partly dupe.