# How to transform columns with method chaining?

Tags: pandas, method-chaining

What's the most fluent (or easy to read) [method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/posts/method-chaining/) solution for transforming columns in Pandas?

(“method chaining” or “fluent” is the [coding style made popular by Tom Augspurger](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/posts/method-chaining/) among others.)

For the sake of the example, let's set up some example data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("iris").astype(str)  # Just for this example
df.loc[1, :] = "NA"

df.head()
# 
#   sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width species
# 0          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 1           NA          NA           NA          NA      NA
# 2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 4          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Just for this example: I want to map certain columns through a function - `sepal_length` using `pd.to_numeric` - while keeping the other columns as they were. What's the easiest way to do that in a method chaining style?

I can already use assign, but I'm repeating the column name here, which I don't want.

```
new_result = (
        df.assign(sepal_length = lambda df_: pd.to_numeric(df_.sepal_length, errors="coerce"))
          .head()  # Further chaining methods, what it may be
    )
```

I can use transform, but transform drops(!) the unmentioned columns. Transform with passthrough for the other columns would be ideal:

```
# Columns not mentioned in transform are lost
new_result = (
        df.transform({'sepal_length': lambda series: pd.to_numeric(series, errors="coerce")})
          .head()  # Further chaining methods...
    )
```

Is there a “best” way to apply transformations to certain columns, in a fluent style, and pass the other columns along?

---

Edit: Below this line, a suggestion after reading Laurent's ideas.

Add a helper function that allows applying a mapping to just one column:

```py
import functools

coerce_numeric = functools.partial(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

def on_column(column, mapping):
    """
    Adaptor that takes a column transformation and returns a "whole dataframe" function suitable for .pipe()
    
    Notice that columns take the name of the returned series, if applicable
    Columns mapped to None are removed from the result.
    """
    def on_column_(df):
        df = df.copy(deep=False)
        res = mapping(df[column])
        # drop column if mapped to None
        if res is None:
            df.pop(column)
            return df
        df[column] = res
        # update column name if mapper changes its name
        if hasattr(res, 'name') and res.name != col:
            df = df.rename(columns={column: res.name})
        return df
    return on_column_
```

This now allows the following neat chaining in the previous example:

```py
new_result = (
        df.pipe(on_column('sepal_length', coerce_numeric))
          .head()  # Further chaining methods...
    )
```

However, I'm still open to ways how to do this just in native pandas without the glue code.

---

Edit 2 to further adapt Laurent's ideas, as an alternative. Self-contained example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col1": ["4", "1", "3", "2"], "col2": [9, 7, 6, 5], "col3": ["w", "z", "x", "y"]}
)

def map_columns(mapping=None, /, **kwargs):
    """
    Transform the specified columns and let the rest pass through.
    
    Examples:
    
        df.pipe(map_columns(a=lambda x: x + 1, b=str.upper))
        
        # dict for non-string column names
        df.pipe({(0, 0): np.sqrt, (0, 1): np.log10})
    """
    if mapping is not None and kwargs:
        raise ValueError("Only one of a dict and kwargs can be used at the same time")
    mapping = mapping or kwargs
    
    def map_columns_(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        mapping_funcs = {**{k: lambda x: x for k in df.columns}, **mapping}
        # preserve original order of columns
        return df.transform({key: mapping_funcs[key] for key in df.columns})
    return map_columns_


df2 = (
    df
    .pipe(map_columns(col2=pd.to_numeric))
    .sort_values(by="col1")
    .pipe(map_columns(col1=lambda x: x.astype(str) + "0"))
    .pipe(map_columns({'col2': lambda x: -x, 'col3': str.upper}))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

df2

#   col1    col2    col3
# 0     10  -7  Z
# 1     20  -5  Y
# 2     30  -6  X
# 3     40  -9  W
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814100/pandas-to-numeric-for-multiple-columns) question and the several answers help ?

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't really address the fluent column transformation in general

Comment: I thought that's what you were asking for. apply a function (eg. pd.to_numeric) to multiple columns (specific ones, but not all). in the link I sent they did exactly that, either by make a list of columns to choose and then with `df[cols].apply` with axis=1 or for `col in cols` or they group columns together with same type. in all of the solution the other columns maintain. maybe I don't get the term "fluent column transformation", then I'm sorry :P

Comment: I've added a link for method chaining. To find a solution in that style is the main focus of the question. I know how to solve the problem in general, and the solutions in your link are certainly helpful, but not what I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on your interesting question.

I don't know of a more idiomatic way in Pandas to do method chaining than combining [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html), [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), or [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html). But I understand that *"transform with passthrough for the other columns would be ideal".*

So, I suggest using it with a higher-order function to deal with other columns, doing even more functional-like coding by taking advantage of Python standard library [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) module.

For example, with the following toy dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col1": ["4", "1", "3", "2"], "col2": [9, 7, 6, 5], "col3": ["w", "z", "x", "y"]}
)
```

You can define the following [partial object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects):

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import Any, Callable
import pandas as pd

def helper(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str, method: Callable[..., Any]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    funcs = {col: method} | {k: lambda x: x for k in df.columns if k != col}
    # preserve original order of columns
    return {key: funcs[key] for key in df.columns}

on = partial(helper, df)
```

And then do all sorts of chain assignments using `transform`, for instance:

```py
df = (
    df
    .transform(on("col1", pd.to_numeric))
    .sort_values(by="col1")
    .transform(on("col2", lambda x: x.astype(str) + "0"))
    .transform(on("col3", str.upper))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(df)
# Ouput
   col1 col2 col3
0     1   70    Z
1     2   50    Y
2     3   60    X
3     4   90    W
```

Comment: Great answer! @Laurent  I really liked the partial approach.

Comment: Interesting ideas! Do you mind if I take this and try to change it into something I'd like to use? I'd like to see if I can avoid the partial (The dataframe should be as it is at the point in the chain, not frozen in the start) - and preferably keep the order of columns at all times - order in == order out is important to me.

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSharma. @creanion I've edited my answer to tweak the helper function so that order of columns is preserved. You can do without `partial`, it was mainly to avoid repeating df, in the DRY spirit you seek. And since df is a mutable object, it is not really 'frozen' after the initial partial assignment. But it's up to you. Cheers.

Comment: `df` won't reflect the result of the method chain, *at that point in the chain*, though, so it doesn't work well with all fluent code. Nothing personal, just looking at the end goal here. With inspiration from you, I've posted another helper function in the question.

Comment: Right. This is getting more and more interesting, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, perhaps using `**` within assign will be helpful. For example, if you just wanted to convert the numeric data types using `pd.to_numeric` the following should work.

```
df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce'))
```

By unpacking the df, you are essentially giving assign what it needs to assign each column. This would be equivalent to writing `sepal_length = pd.to_numeric(df['sepal_length'],errors='coerce'), sepal_width = ...` for each column.