# How can i change dtype from object to float64 in a column, using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I extracted some data from ***investing*** but columns values are all **dtype = object**, so i cant work with them...
how should i **convert object to float**?

(`2558    6.678,08 2557    6.897,23 2556    7.095,95 2555    7.151,21 2554    7.093,34 ...    4       4.050,38 3       4.042,63 2       4.181,13 1       4.219,56 0       4.223,33 Name: Alta, Length: 2559, dtype: object`)

What i want is :
`2558   6678.08 2557    6897.23 2556    7095.95 2555    7151.21 2554    7093.34 ...    4       4050.38 3       4042.63 2       4181.13 1       4219.56 0       4223.33 Name: Alta, Length: 2559, dtype: float`

Tried to use the a function which would replace , for .

`def clean(x): x = x.replace(".", "").replace(",",".")`

but it ***doesnt work cause dtype is object***

Thanks!

Comment: can you clear what is your input and what output you expect ?

Comment: i already edited @ManishKumarSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your local locale uses commas as decimal signs, you can use [locale.atof](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/locale.html#locale.atof) (if not you'll first have to set an appropriate locale):

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['6.678,08','6.897,23'], name='Alta')
>>> s
0    6.678,08
1    6.897,23
Name: Alta, dtype: object
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')
'de_DE.UTF-8'
>>> s.apply(locale.atof)
0    6678.08
1    6897.23
Name: Alta, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ty so much! it really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

refer to: [How to convert datatype:object to float64 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277137/how-to-convert-datatypeobject-to-float64-in-python)

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[:,i] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,i], errors='ignore')
    # errors='ignore' lets strings remain as 'non-null objects'
```

this can convert all numerical values to float64 or int64.

Answer (score 0):

To replace your values, try this. result is your dataframe, col is your column name

```
result[col] = result[col].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(".","").str.replace(",","."))
```

If you need to convert this variable to a float, try this

```
result[col] = result[col].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank u but it didnt work...it keeps appearing ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.678,08'...

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is a comma between the value
Because a float cannot have a comma, you need to first replace the comma and then convert it into float
result[col] = result[col].str.replace(",","").astype(float)

Comment: Changing the locale seems to be a more useful solution.